# Could you use the memory allocated by one call of malloc for various variable types?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

im currently learning about dynamically using memory and i was wondering, could you allocate lets say 40 bytes with one call of malloc and use like 16 of them for int variables and the rest 24 for doubles? Im asking this because i know that i have to cast the pointer type to use malloc without warnings. So if i used a void pointer could i do something like what i mentioned?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can. Sure, depends on details. For example can get into troubles with alignment.

Comment: You can put those into a `struct` and allocate memory for the `struct`.

Comment: *"I have to cast the pointer type to use `malloc`"*. Please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Yes you can, but I'd advise against it. Use a `struct` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... could you allocate lets say 40 bytes with one call of malloc and use like 16 of them for int variables and the rest 24 for doubles?

Yes, with some limitations.

The pointer returned by `malloc()` and friends is properly aligned for all standard object types.

The trick: is the address for the 2nd type (`double` in OP's case), properly aligned for `double` if it is 16 bytes away?  Likely yes in OP's case, but maybe not if the `BYTES_FOR_INT` was say 20 and not 16.

A convenient approach is to use a `struct`.

```
#define BYTES_FOR_INT    16
#define BYTES_FOR_DOUBLE 24
struct {
   int i[BYTES_FOR_INT/sizeof(int)];
   double d[BYTES_FOR_DOUBLE/sizeof(double)];
} *st = malloc(sizeof *st);`
#define BYTE_TOTAL (sizeof *st)
```

The above may allocate other than `BYTES_FOR_INT + BYTES_FOR_DOUBLE` bytes, depending on their values and type alignment needs.

To fix the allocation to `BYTE_TOTAL` (40) and `BYTES_FOR_INT` to various values 2-32 takes more work to determine `BYTES_FOR_DOUBLE`.  Padding needs to be considered when `BYTES_FOR_INT, BYTES_FOR_DOUBLE, BYTE_TOTAL` are not convenient multiples of the size of `double`..

---

> i know that i have to cast the pointer type to use malloc without warnings

No. Casting is not needed here in C.  The `void *` returned by `malloc()` converts to other object pointer types with no issues.

Comment: C11 defines `_Alignof` as a unary operator (works like `sizeof`) to get the alignment required of any type or expression.